# Tensorflow installation stuck at "Collecting tensorboard<1.14.0,>=1.13.0 (from tensorflow)"

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, pip

I'm trying to install Tensorflow through pip in the Windows 10 command prompt, however the installation never gets past "Collecting tensorboard<1.14.0,>=1.13.0 (from tensorflow)". I have been able to successfully install other libraries like matplotlib and numpy with pip.

I have tried installing tensorboard, but that gets stuck at "Collecting tensorboard". I have tried deleting and re-installing Python, but that didn't change anything. I have tried running an admin powershell, but that also didn't change anything.

Thank you very much!

Edit: Running "pip install tensorflow -vvv" gets stuck at "Caching due to etag", which is contained within "Collecting tensorboard<1.14.0,>=1.13.0 (from tensorflow)"

Comment: Run `pip install tensorflow -vvv` and add the output to the quedtion.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem with the version of python installation, by running the installation command with -vvv, you might see something like 
`Skipping link: none of the wheel's tags match: cp37-cp37m...` among others. For example, if you are running windows, tensorflow is not available for python 3.7 (as seen [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package-location))